# Scalar invariance and dimensions

Tags: cosmology, distance, scale-invariance

I recently read an [interesting article](http://www.wired.com/2014/08/multiverse/) on scale invariance.

It discussed how modern physics is suggesting that scalar units really may not apply above the Planck Level. Here is a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance) that helped me anyway.

My question is, does scalar invariance suggest distances in light years versus microns may not even exist but are how humans perceive and organize physical properties that we call length, height, time, ect. Could 'distant' galaxies actually be far closer than our perceptions suggest?

Comment: Do you mean "scale invariance" rather than "scalar invariance"?

Comment: No its scalar invariance my understanding is Planck scale is an invariant scale and from my limited knowledge the articles states: "Nature, at the deepest level, may not differentiate between scales" I believe it is also referred to as scale symmetry

Comment: In that case you might want to add some links to resources where people unfamiliar with the concept can read about it. "Scale invariance" is well known, but I've never heard of "scalar invariance".